# API Pardot SSO Necessary Changes

Tags: api, pardot

I am attempting to adopt the OAuth changes which are necessary for the new SSO Pardot requirements. I will need to replace this API login which is currently used :

```
public with sharing class Http_Utility_Pardot {
    
  /*
     * @Method Name  :   login
     * 
     * @Description  :   Login into Pardot and get the API_KEY for further transactions
     * 
     * @Args    :   Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt
     * 
     * @Return    :   String
     *
     *
   */
    public static String login(Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt pardotTrackingConfig) {
        
        String requestBody = 'email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.UserName__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                + '&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.Passward__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                + '&user_key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.User_Key__c, Constants.UTF_8);
                                
        HttpRequest request= HTTPRequestBuilder.buildHTTPRequest(pardotTrackingConfig.Login_URL__c, 
                                                                    Constants.POST,
                                                                    Constants.APPLICATIONX_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED, 
                                                                    null, requestBody);
        HttpResponse response = HTTPService.send(request);
        return HTTPResponseParser.parseLoginResponse(response);
    }


  public static String pardotCreateProspect(Set<Id> contactIds) {
        
        // Querying the Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt record
        List<Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt> pardotTrackingConfigs = [SELECT Id, Login_URL__c, UserName__c, Passward__c, User_Key__c,
                                                                            Email_Tracking_URL__c, Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c, Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c
                                                                            FROM Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'Pardot_Tracking_Data'];
        
        if(pardotTrackingConfigs.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_PTC_Not_Defined;
        
        //Login into Pardot to get the API_KEY
        String apiKey = login(pardotTrackingConfigs[0]);
        //String pardotReturnedResponse = '';
        
        // Check if contactIds is null
        if(contactIds.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Contact_Id_Missing;
            
        // Querying the particular Contact details for the creation of Prospect record  
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactIds];
        if(contacts.size() == 0)
            return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Invalid_Contact;

            String endpoint;
            String requestBody;
            Map<String, String> headerParameters= new Map<String, String>{'Authorization' => 'Pardot api_key='+ apiKey + ',user_key='+pardotTrackingConfigs[0].User_Key__c};

            if(contacts.size() == 1){  
                Contact contactRecord = contacts[0];  
            endpoint = pardotTrackingConfigs[0].Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c + contactRecord.Email;

            requestBody = 'first_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&last_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8);
                                    //+ '&crm_owner_fid=' + contactRecord.OwnerId;

        } else {
        
            endpoint = pardotTrackingConfigs[0].Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c;
            requestBody = '';
            for(Contact contactRecord:contacts){
                                                        
                requestBody = requestBody +'{"email":"' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                          + '","first_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                          + '","last_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                          //+ '","crm_owner_fid":"'+ contactRecord.OwnerId+ '"},';
                                          + '",},';

                }
                
                requestBody = 'prospects={"prospects":['+ requestBody.removeEnd(',')+']}';
        }
        
        HttpRequest request= HTTPRequestBuilder.buildHTTPRequest(endpoint, Constants.POST,
                                                                        Constants.APPLICATIONX_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED,
                                                                        headerParameters, requestBody);

        HttpResponse response = HTTPService.send(request);
        return HTTPResponseParser.parseCreateRecordResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Are there any examples of how to replace this type of login with the OAuth requirements ?

Comment: There isn't much to go on in your post. Have you dug into your Http_Utility_Pardot class and debugged from there? When you / your team refactored the code to handle Pardot requiring SSO logins, was this change propagated throughout your environments?

Comment: It has been identified to be related that exact issue. Our team was never notified that these changes were coming and we are now stuck with these new changes. We will now be looking into making OAuth and Apex changes.

Answer (score 0):

It has been identified to be related that exact issue. Our team was never notified that these changes were coming and we are now stuck with these new changes. We will now be looking into making OAuth and Apex changes.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post I wrote, it might help you out: https://thespotforpardot.com/2021/02/02/pardot-api-and-getting-ready-with-salesforce-sso-users-part-3a-connecting-to-pardot-api-from-apex/

Comment: Thank you so much @AdamErstelle. This article looks great. I will be looking at this article over the next couple days. My biggest concern is the Apex portion.

Comment: @AdamErstelle - Thank you very much for referencing that blog. I have set up the first four steps of the whole blog (connected app ; certificate ; named credential). But I'm not really sure which should be my next steps as I am dealing with here. I see you also had another blog that went into Python coding, but I don't think that would apply here. Any help you can give would be very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your next steps would be to look at the Sample Working APEX, compare it with your own and see what adjustments need to be made. This can vary wildly depending on how your code is written.  If you like, you can also reach out to us at www.sercante.com and we can look at a small support arrangement!

Comment: @AdamErstelle - Thank you very much. I attempted to use the Apex in the blog but am getting an error with row 4, telling me Invalid identifier '‘callout'. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters. Any input you can give on that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Zoom_v, it seems you've identified a solution or at least the changes you need to make. Could you edit your answer to include details for future users that come across this post?

Comment: @nbrown - I actually do not have a solution or the necessary changes. I am attempting to use a site which provides potential problems but since I cannot get that solution to work in my environment I cannot understand what other changes I will need in order to relate it to the current setup. If you have any feedback you can provide I would be very grateful.